# Poke holes [blank] an argument

Tags: prepositions

Do we "poke holes **at** an argument" or "poke holes **in** an argument?" Or something else?

Comment: Holes aren't holes unless they're **in** something.  You can poke **at** something.  You could say "poke at an argument", which would be grammatically correct but not normal usage. or "poke holes in an argument", which is the normal expression.

Answer (score 0):

***Poke holes at*** is rarely used in a figurative sense ([Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=poke%20holes%20in%2C%20poke%20holes%20at&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpoke%20holes%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpoke%20holes%20at%3B%2Cc0)).

[Poke holes in an argument](https://www.google.it/search?q=poke%20holes%20in%20an%20argument&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT606IT607&hl=it&prmd=ivsn&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6wL3eoPHTAhWLaFAKHbh6DuoQ_AUIDigG&biw=768&bih=909) usage examples:

From [Infusion: 90 Daily Doses of Wisdom, Truth and Encouragement](https://books.google.it/books?id=4UYvZoFIKr4C&q=%22poke%20holes%20in%20an%22&dq=%22poke%20holes%20in%20an%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwipl_qkn_HTAhVjBMAKHd4oDQ0Q6AEIHzAB)

> - A submitted student of Scripture ***is not trying to poke holes in an argument with a condescending attitude***. If this is the case, he has missed the point of searching the Scripture for truth. The reason you seek to validate a message from Scripture  ...

Comment: Do you know why "in" might be preferable to "at"? Or is it just arbitrary.

Comment: @Kenny LJ - I think it is because of its more common literal usage.

Comment: Once you poke the holes in the argument, it won't hold water.  If you just poke at it, it may still hold water.